# jQuerys lack of JSON.stringify

Tags: jquery, json

jQuery uses `JSON.parse()` for a cross-browser solution when converting JSON-strings to objects using `jQuery.parseJSON()`:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string") {
        return null;
    }

    // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
    data = jQuery.trim( data );

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
    // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
    if ( rvalidchars.test( data.replace( rvalidescape, "@" )
        .replace( rvalidtokens, "]" )
        .replace( rvalidbraces, "")) ) {

        return ( new Function( "return " + data ) )();

    }
    jQuery.error( "Invalid JSON: " + data );
}
```

But why isn't there a similar solution for converting objects to JSON using `JSON.stringify`? `JSON.stringify` doesn't work in IE7 for example, unless you include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). Is it something that's on jQuerys roadmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a similar solution because jQuery internally does not need it. The current stance on it is If the core doesn't need it, and it can be implemented using generally accepted methods *(including json2.js or using the one built into all modern browsers)* it doesn't need to be in the core.

For reference, https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-encodejson

Comment: Guess ill have to stick to a conditional comment and include it in ie7 then. Thanks